# outlook vba - move email to folder, object required

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write some vba which will move emails as they are received into a certain folder.

The code, so far, is:

```
Private WithEvents myItems as Outlook.Items
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim myApp as Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace as Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox as Outlook.Folder

    Set myApp = Outlook.Application
    Set myNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item as Object)
    Dim msg as Outlook.MailItem
    Dim recips as String
    Dim destFolder as Outlook.Folder

    Set destFolder = myInbox.Folders("Test")
    Set msg = item
    recips = msg.To
    If InStr(recips, "m0atz") Then
          msg.Move destFolder
    End If

    Set msg = nothing
    Set destFolder = nothing
End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is an error when an email is received from this line:

```
Set destFolder = myInbox.Folders("Test")
```

saying "run-time error 424 - Object Required"

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myInbox` is a local variable of `Application_Startup`. Thus, it's only accessible in `Application_Startup`.

I *strongly* recommend to add `Option Explicit On` to the top of your module. This will alert you of such errors (and others).

To solve your problem, either

- discover `myInbox` again in your `myItems_ItemAdd` method (you might want to extract your Application_Startup code into a method for that) or
- declare `myInbox` outside your method (just like `myItems`) to make it globally accessible. Note that such "global variables" should be used sparingly and only if really necessary.

Comment: works a charm! thanks Heinzi, noted about option explicit, many thanks.